# How to remove properties of a json document in mysql using the select statement with a wildcard expression

Tags: mysql, json

I know that in mysql u can just remove properties like so..

```
SELECT JSON_REMOVE('{"key1": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abc"}, "key2": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abcd"}}','$."1"')
```

Result

```
{"key2": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abcd"}}
```

However, running this query which would presumably have to remove the "l" property, removes nothing.

```
SELECT JSON_REMOVE('{"key1": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abc"}, "key2": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abcd"}}','$.*.l')
```

Gives me the error of

> In this situation, path expressions may not contain the * and **
>   tokens.

Is there any other way to remove properties of a child property without knowing their names while using the select statement? Please consider the code examples I have provided as they might make it a little bit easier to understand my question.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 or 8.0?

Comment: 5.7.27 on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: It's doable in a query in 8.0 but in 5.7 I think you'll have to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.7 you can do this with a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE strip_property(IN j JSON, IN pname TEXT, OUT newj TEXT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE nkeys INT;
  DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
  SET @o = '{}';
  SELECT JSON_KEYS(j) INTO @keys;
  SELECT JSON_LENGTH(@keys) INTO nkeys;
  WHILE n < nkeys DO
    SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@keys, '$[", n, "]')) INTO @k");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SET @sql = CONCAT("SET @o = JSON_INSERT(@o, '$.", @k, "', JSON_REMOVE(JSON_EXTRACT('", j, "', '$.", @k, "'), '$.", pname, "'))");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SET n = n + 1;
  END WHILE;
  SET newj = @o;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Example:

```
SET @j = '{"key1": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abc"}, "key2": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abcd"}}';
CALL strip_property(@j, 'l', @result);
SELECT @result;
```

Output:

```
{"key1": {"n": "abc"}, "key2": {"n": "abcd"}}
```

In MYSQL 8+, it gets a lot easier as we have access to the [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) and [`JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) functions:

```
SET @j = '{"key1": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abc"}, "key2": {"l": ["186"], "n": "abcd"}}';

SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(`key`, JSON_REMOVE(value, "$.l"))
FROM JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(@j),
                "$[*]"
                COLUMNS (rn FOR ORDINALITY,
                         `key` VARCHAR(100) PATH "$")
                ) k
JOIN JSON_TABLE(@j,
                "$.*"
                COLUMNS (rn FOR ORDINALITY,
                         value JSON PATH "$")
                ) j ON j.rn = k.rn;
```

Output:

```
{"key1": {"n": "abc"}, "key2": {"n": "abcd"}}
```

I've made a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rMwjhFyc7kkGueeN4ouner/2) of both solutions on dbfiddle.com

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?